# Solving equation $f(x) = (1-x)^{\alpha + 1}-\ell (x+1)^{\alpha + 1} + 2 \ell (\alpha + 1) x^{\alpha} = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have been having trouble solving the following equation for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ with $0<\alpha<1$ and $\ell >1$. \begin{equation}
f(x) = (1-x)^{\alpha + 1}-\ell (x+1)^{\alpha + 1} + 2 \ell (\alpha + 1) x^{\alpha}.
\end{equation}
Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: $x=0$ seems to do the job, isn't it?

Comment: No, graphically for $\alpha>\frac 12$ there seems to be 2 positive roots, one rather small and another that goes to infinity as $\ell$ increases. For $\alpha<\frac 12$ there seems to be a small negative root as well. Since OP restricted $x\in[0,1]$ he may be interested only in the small positive root. Now, formalizing that is another story...

Comment: @zwim I agree with you that finding all solutions is certainly an interesting question but OP did not restrict to $0<x<1$...

Comment: @Surb, x=0 doesn't work. We get $f(0) = 1-l$

Comment: Simulposted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377211/does-the-following-equation-fx-0-have-an-analytic-solution

Comment: I expanded with MacLaurin and found that the root is accurate wrt Newton method $$2 (\alpha+1) \ell x^{\alpha}-(\alpha+1) (\ell+1) x-\ell+1=0$$ but has no analytic closed solution

Comment: Thanks for all the help.